# What is the difference between pure and mempty in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids

In shool, I was task to write a function which appends Numbers to the left side of a list,  if they are even. The type-signature was given as:

```
appendIfEven :: (Applicative f, Monoid (f a), Integral a) => a -> f a -> f a
```

My answer was the following piece of code

```
appendIfEven :: (Applicative f, Monoid (f a), Integral a) => a -> f a -> f a
appendIfEven x ms = if x `mod` 2 == 0 then mempty x `mappend` ms else ms
```

Haskell can compile my code, but it does not work properly. After some experimenting, I switched *mempty* to *pure* :

```
appendIfEven :: (Applicative f, Monoid (f a), Integral a) => a -> f a -> f a
appendIfEven x ms = if x `mod` 2 == 0 then pure x `mappend` ms else ms
```

Which works fin. But why ? shouldn't *pure* == *mempty* ? (In this context)
It seems to be not important for my Tutor. However I would really like to understand a bit more about Haskell and where I am wrong ....

Comment: Well they have different types, for one. How could they be the same thing if they have different types?

Comment: It compiled because `a -> b` has a `Monoid` instance as long as `b` is also a `Monoid`, in which case `mempty = const mempty`.

Comment: @user253751 `a -> b` has a `Monoid` instance, in which case `mempty` itself is also a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider applying this to lists.

```
mempty == []

pure 5 = [5]
```

Those don't look very similar to me. In particular, `mempty x` ought to be ill-typed.

Basically `mempty` gives you an *empty* thing, whereas `pure x` gives you a thing with an `x` in it.

Comment: `mempty` is defined for `Monoid b => a -> b` to be `const mempty`.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, I had a feeling that the compiler doesn't complain because a suitable instance either does exist or theoretically could be made to exist. Still doesn't make it a sensible expression (unless you really are using such an instance).

Comment: In proper context, it can make sense to use `mempty` as a function. Instead, IMO, it makes no sense to immediately apply it as in `mempty x` since it's equivalent (in the same context) to `mempty`.

Comment: the functions instance is what makes possible the famous trick `comparing snd <> comparing fst`, with `(f <> g) x y = (f x <> g x) y = f x y <> g x y`.

Answer (score 5):

You inadvertently used an unexpected monoid, which incidentally made your code compile.

When you wrote `` mempty x `mappend` ms ``, the `ms` value has type `f a`, which is a monoid. This forces `mempty x` to have the same type, since `mappend` requires two arguments of the same type. Hence we must have

```
mempty x :: f a
```

which implies, since `x :: a`,

```
mempty :: a -> f a
```

Weird, right?

Well, it happens that there is an instance in the libraries

```
instance Monoid t => Monoid (u -> t) where
   mempty = \_ -> mempty
   ...
```

which you inadvertently used passing `x` to `mempty`, since `t` can be `f a`, and `u` can be `a` in the instance above. Haskell resolved the monoid constraint so to use this instance.

This also means that

```
mempty x `mappend` ms
```

is the same as

```
(\_ -> mempty) x `mappend` ms  -- this is the mempty for (f a), instead!
```

which is the same as

```
mempty `mappend` ms   -- this is the mempty for (f a), instead!
```

which is the same as

```
ms
```

Hence, your code completely ignores the `x` argument.

By contrast `pure x` does depend on `x`, in the general case, so the end result can be very different.